# Node JS Sequelize raw query is changing the table names to lowercase in Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am building a Node JS application. I am using the Sequelize package for the database. My database is Postgres. But I am having a little problem running the raw query.

Here is my function:

```
const [ results, metadata ] = database.sequelize.query("UPDATE UserTeams SET status=:status", {
      replacements: { status: 1 },
      type: QueryTypes.UPDATE
    })
```

When I run the code, I am getting the following error.

```
'relation "userteams" does not exist'
```

I assume that is because it changed the table name to lowercase. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Try `'UPDATE "UserTeams" SET status=:status'`